# Как правильно передать в функцию массив указателей?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы, параметры

Я создала функцию, которая принимает массив `int` (указатель на указатель), значение максимума и минимума, и возвращает массив, который состоит уже лишь из чисел, которые лежат в промежутке `min - max` и размер этого "нового" массива.

Но я никак не могу проверить корректность работы функции, так как не могу правильно создать этот массив `int`'ов и заполнить его значениями :(

Я только начинаю, пожалуйста не судите строго.

Вот функция, которую я создала:

```
int ft_ultimate_range(int** range, int min, int max)
{
    int size;
    int i;
    size = max - min;
    i = 0;

    if (size <= 0)
        return (0);

    *range = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    while (min < max)
    {
        *range[i] = min;
        min++;
        i++;
    }

    return (size);
}
```

А вот массив, который я пытаюсь в нее передать:

```
int* arra[10];
int indexX, indexY;
int i;

indexX = 0;
indexY = 0;

while (arra[indexX][indexY])
{
    while (arra[indexX][indexY])
    {
        arra[indexX][indexY] = indexY;
        printf("%d\n", arra[indexX][indexY]);
        indexY++;
    }

    indexX++;
    indexY = 0;
}

i = ft_ultimate_range(arra, 1, 5);
printf("%d\n", i);
//Ничего не выводится
```

На строке с заполнением массива выдает ошибку:

> ERROR: Use of uninitialised value of size 8.

Comment: `while(arra[indexX][indexY])` - это что? В вашем примере нет заполнения массива

Comment: А как его правильно заполнить? Это я пытаюсь пройтись по элементам массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, здесь

```
while (arra[indexX][indexY])
```

вы вообще используете некоторое непонятное значение для записи. Подумайте сами - у вас есть массив из 10 указателей, указывающих не пойми куда - и вы пытаетесь обратиться по этим адресам как к массивам - что совсем невесело...

А главное - непонятно, что и зачем вы делаете. Ведь дальше вы пытаетесь передать этот "массив" в функцию, в которой благополучно его перезаписать (ваша `malloc()`).

Вобщем, понять, что вы вообще делаете, не удается; если опишете словами нормально - придумаем, как решить :)

А пока - если я верно понял, то самую первую функцию вы хотите использовать, чтоб выделить в памяти новый массив и заполнить его числами `min`, `min+1`, `min+1`, ..., `max-1`? Так? (судя по вашему коду)

Тогда проще сделать так:

```
int * min_max_range(int min, int max)
{
    int size = max-min;
    int * range = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        range[i] = min+i;
    return range;
}
```

Но, еще раз - что вы делаете - непонятно. Сформулируйте задание. Например, **зачем** вы передаете в функцию массив? когда вам нужно массив вернуть...

**Update**

```
int min_max_range(int ** range, int min, int max)
{
    int size = max-min;
    if (size <= 0) { *range = NULL; return 0; }
    *range = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        (*range)[i] = min+i;
    return size;
}

int * arr;
min_max_range(&arr,1,5);
```